# What's the purpose of the GtkWidget.events property for (like) GtkTreeView widgets?

Tags: linux, gtk, pygtk, glade

I have a Glade GUI description file with a `GtkTreeView` in a `GtkHBox` in a window; and there's a handler for the `row_activated` signal. Now, Glade has automatically set the "events" property (inherited from `GtkWidget`) of that treeview to some value (`GDK_POINTER_MOTION_MASK | GDK_POINTER_MOTION_HINT_MASK | GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK | GDK_BUTTON_RELEASE_MASK`). And there are two strange things with this:

- removing the pre-set value (so that the property is empty) doesn't seem to break the application (at least not with the old GTK 2.10 I have atm).
- in fact, an annoying bug I has seen before (where the treeview items would not correctly react to expand or collapse clicks) is now gone!

I have yet to test this with a newer GTK version, but the question is already there: exactly what is the purpose for this `events` property? And why does Glade automatically and unnecessarily set it to some value? Does this have some side effects I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in glade, it always sets the event property of widgets it create. It has no notion of the default value of a property so it always sets it.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this mask indicate the events you're willing to receive?  In this case, you'll probably want to receive notification that the user has clicked or double-clicked an item in the GtkTreeView, and you'll want to register callbacks to handle these events.

Answer (score 0):

me.yahoo.com/a/kUQ7zeQ: but even if I set the property to an empty string as mentioned, the `row_activated` handler is still called when I double-click on a row (or press Enter or Space). So the treeview still gets events...